# Deprecating picklist items in Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, deprecated

With CRM systems, its useful to be able to 'deprecate' picklist items. Typically, deprecated picklist items cannot be picked by users for new records, but will correctly display for older records that still reference them. This is often more convenient than deleting picklist items because historical records do not need to be updated.

An example: imagine a picklist of animals, used to record people's favourite animal. After some time we want to remove 'Chinchilla' from the list (for some reason) so we deprecate it. From then on, 'Chinchilla' is not an option in the picklist for new records. But when looking at older records of people whose favourite animal was Chinchilla, it still diplays correctly.

Whats a good way of doing this in Dynamics CRM 2011?

I found a [good blog post by Shoaib Faruq](http://shoaibfaruq.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/to-make-an-attribute-obsoletedelete-in-dropdown-list-picklist-in-crm/) describing how to do it in Dynamics CRM 4, but it involves custom javascript in the OnLoad event, I'm wondering if there's a neater way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe JavaScript would be the best option here. I can't really think of a nicer way to achieve this.